Any help to pull information from Quickbooks would be greatly appreciated
The code is below, with the error messages that are generated.
import win32com.client
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def connect_to_quickbooks():
    """Establishes a connection to QuickBooks Desktop."""
    try:
        qb = win32com.client.Dispatch("QBXMLRP2.RequestProcessor")
        qb.OpenConnection("", "QBXML Test App")
        qb.BeginSession("", 2)  # 2 = qbFileOpenDoNotCare
        return qb
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error connecting to QuickBooks:", str(e))
        return None

def test_qbxml_request(qb, request_type):
    """Tests a minimal QBXML request."""
    try:
        # Generate a basic QBXML request based on the request_type
        request = f"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="13.0"?>
        <QBXML>
          <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
            <{request_type} />
          </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>
        """
        print(f"Sending {request_type} request...")
        response = qb.ProcessRequest(request)
        print(f"Raw Response for {request_type}:", response)  # Debugging output
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during {request_type}:", str(e))
        return None

def parse_response(response, tag_name):
    """Parses the QBXML response and extracts elements by tag name."""
    try:
        root = ET.fromstring(response)
        elements = root.findall(f".//{tag_name}")
        print(f"Extracted {len(elements)} elements with tag '{tag_name}'")
        for element in elements:
            print(ET.tostring(element, encoding='unicode'))
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error parsing response for {tag_name}:", str(e))

def main():
    """Main function to test QBXML requests."""
    qb = connect_to_quickbooks()
    if not qb:
        return

    try:
        # Test Company Query
        company_response = test_qbxml_request(qb, "CompanyQueryRq")
        if company_response:
            parse_response(company_response, "CompanyName")

        # Test Customer Query
        customer_response = test_qbxml_request(qb, "CustomerQueryRq")
        if customer_response:
            parse_response(customer_response, "CustomerRet")

        # Test Invoice Query
        invoice_response = test_qbxml_request(qb, "InvoiceQueryRq")
        if invoice_response:
            parse_response(invoice_response, "InvoiceRet")
    finally:
        # Close the session and connection gracefully
        try:
            qb.EndSession()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error during EndSession:", str(e))
        try:
            qb.CloseConnection()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error during CloseConnection:", str(e))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

C:\python>py invoiceexport.py
Sending CompanyQueryRq request...
Error during CompanyQueryRq: (-2147352562, 'Invalid number of parameters.', None, None)
Sending CustomerQueryRq request...
Error during CustomerQueryRq: (-2147352562, 'Invalid number of parameters.', None, None)
Sending InvoiceQueryRq request...
Error during InvoiceQueryRq: (-2147352562, 'Invalid number of parameters.', None, None)
Error during EndSession: (-2147352562, 'Invalid number of parameters.', None, None)

I know the program is accessing the Quickbooks system because I had to enable the program when first running it. I gave the program full access to the Quickbooks file, even if Quickbooks is not running.
I keep getting "Invalid number of parameters" but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.
